# Django CreateView success message not shown

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a CreateView and an UpdateView with success messages in both. But, only the UpdateView success message works and the CreateView message isn't show. Why is this happening?

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
 class CreateRedirect (CreateView):
        model = MarketingRedirect
        template_name = 'marketing_redirect/create_redirect.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('backend_redirect')
        fields = ['redirect_from', 'redirect_to']
        success_message = "Redirect successfully created!"


    class EditRedirect(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
        model = MarketingRedirect
        fields = ['redirect_from', 'redirect_to']
        template_name = 'marketing_redirect/edit_redirect.html'
        context_object_name = 'redirect'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('backend_redirect')
        success_message = 'Review successfully updated'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inherit **SuccessMessageMixin** for class CreateRedirect as shown below:

```
class CreateRedirect(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    ....
```

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, it is already there. It is working for update view but not for create view

Comment: @DeA I have edited my answer, check and implement the same.

Comment: That was really stupid of me to even be asking here. Sorry for was wasting your time and thank you!

Comment: The relevant django link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views